# Android - ListViews, ArrrayAdapters, Fragments and ClassNotFoundExceptions

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I'm having some difficulty with ListViews, ArrayAdapters and Fragments in Android where inflating an .xml file which contains a  tag causes a ClassNotFoundException. I'm running Android 4.0.3 FWIW. Here's what my main activity class looks like:

```
public class MarketActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

private ListView marketListView;

private MarketAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.market);
   marketListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.market_list_view);
   updateView();
}

private void updateView() {
    BfMarket market = ((MarketController) getController()).getMarket();
    BfRunner runners = market.getRunners();

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new MarketAdapter(this, R.layout.market_row, runners.getRunners());
    }
    if (marketListView != null && runners != null) {
        marketListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        marketListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        adapter.setRunners(runners.getRunners());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

the layout file (R.layout.market) for the MarketActivity includes a ListView like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/market_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

The MarketAdapter class is a simple ArrayAdapter which looks like this:

```
public class MarketAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Runner> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "MarketAdapter";

private ArrayList<Runner> runners;
private BfMarket market;

public MarketAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Runner> runners) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, runners);
    this.runners = runners;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.market_row, parent, false);
    }
    MarketRunner runner = (MarketRunner) runners.get(position);
```

The code fails at the following point:

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.market_row, parent, false);
```

market_row has the following tag (which I think is causing all the trouble):

```
<fragment class="com.my.app.DummyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/embedded"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

My DummyFragment is very simple:

```
public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
}
```

}

A couple of troubleshooting things that I've already tried:

Ensured that my MarketActivity was referencing the correct support APIs. Here's the import I have at the top of my MarketActivity class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder of my project and it's on the project's classpath too. I get the feeling that the compatibility package is having difficulty reading in the  tag which I have declared in market_row.xml. Either it cannot find the class associated with the fragment tag or I'm using an incorrect LayoutInflater? All suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks,

Sean

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1777)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1793)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3848)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:211)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
   at com.test.base.activities.TabbedStoreActivity.onCreate(TabbedStoreActivity.java:46)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1731)
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole piece :

```
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.market_row, parent, false);
}
```

is excessive. You had already set the item layout when creating the new ArrayAdapter. It remembers it and will do all the work on creating the item and will do it only when necessary.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532548/715269).

Comment: Hi Gangus - thanks for the optimization pointer, but I'm not sure it will solve my original question. One place where the if (v == null) check is useful though is if you want to use a ViewHolder pattern to reduce the number of findViewById calls. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html has some more details on this.